# SDK manager does not show sample package option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I followed the android [developer link to install sample](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) package.

However, when I expand the package list of Android platform, there is no "**Sample for SDK**" option (checkbox) available. Why??

I have installed Android from version 2.3.3(API10) to 4.0.3(API 15), none of them contain the option for downloading sample package. Why?

Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: how did you resolve yr problem?  I've same problem please help!

Answer (score 0):

//you need to download it there is an option for that.

if it show already installed you need to go to the folder called `<sdk>/samples/`

Actually its not there in that folder `<sdk>/platforms/<android-version>/samples/`

[image]

Comment: Hi, my question is that I do not have the option for downloading samples in SDK manager. I do not have either <sdk>/samples/ or <sdk>/platforms/<android-version>/samples either.  I want to download the samples, but have no way to do it.

Comment: @Leem.fin in this below Android SDK manager Show: updates/new you need to check and install that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update the Tools packages.

Install the updates (may need to do this multiple times) to get the latest version. Then close the Sdk manager, reopen it and the sample package should be available!

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced same problem.. I found solution here go to this link and download samples for all versions of sdk

http://www.hariadi.org/android/manual-download-of-android-sdk-components/