# Can't download Android sdk samples for platform 15

Tags: android, sample

I downloaded and installed the android sdk 15 on my Ubuntu laptop.
Everything works fine but I can't download the sdk samples.
Are they available ????
I followed the instructions of this page http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html but can't see the option download and install samples in the dialog.

Comment: SDK manager does not show sample package option http://stackoverflow.com/a/11454618/1012284

Comment: Thx a lot Padma! It's the same issue, I didn't see it before posting mine. Well will try to update my tools in the sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android sdk manager, he indicates you about install sample or notinstall. If notinstall then tell you about error. And check space on HDD (can be).
And read this article [install sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/exploring.html)
Thanks at time.

Comment: Thanks for your help imperator_sp but it's not related to the disk space.

Answer (score 0):

//you need to download it there is an option for that.

if it show already installed you need to go to the folder called `<sdk>/samples/`

Actually its not there in that folder `<sdk>/platforms/<android-version>/samples/`